# Unsubscribing from Profile Center (%%profile_center_url%%) or Subscription Center (%%subscription_center_url%%) doesn't work

Tags: marketing-cloud, email

I'm running into a slightly weird issue.  When I use the personalization string `%%subscription_center_url%%` or `%%profile_center_url%%` I cannot seem to unsubscribe via these ways.  Meaning, I click on the link in the email that points to either `%%subscription_center_url%%` or `%%profile_center_url%%`, then I'm taken to the profile center or subscription center (see screenshot):

[image]

There's an option at the bottom of the page to allow the subscriber to unsubscribe from ALL publications.  When I do this and then check All Subscribers in Marketing Cloud for my particular email address, I'm still showing as Active (not unsubscribed).

The flip side is if I use the personalization string `%%unsub_center_url%%` - this works.  I can click on this link, then click "Unsubscribe from all".  I then check Marketing Cloud's All Subs list for my email address and it now shows as unsubscribed.

Any ideas why the first two won't work?

Answer (score 2):

unsub_center_ur - this will unsubscribe you from All Subscribers i.e. it's a global unsubscribe.

Using profile_center_url or subscription_center_url to 'Unsubscribe From All' will unsubscribe you from ALL publications i.e. the publication lists 'Account & Credit Union Information' 'Employer Blog' etc.

profile_center_url or subscription_center_url unsubscribe doesn't Unsubscribe you from 'All Subscribers' but unsubscribes you from the individual publication lists.

If you check the publication lists, you will see that you have been unsubscribed from there.

If you want to unsubscribe the customer from 'All Subscribers' then you will need to use unsub_center_url - this will prevent any commercial emails from being sent to that SubscriberKey